# Display div with ID that matches data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to display div's with ID's that match the data attribute of the selected list item. 
Below is the code, I think I'm nearly there I just need to get the specific value of the data attribute.  I'll keep trying but some help would be great :)

```
.hide {
  display: none;
}

<ul class="list-filter">
  <li data-target="#example1">Example 1</li>
  <li data-target="#example2">Example 2</li>
</ul>

<div class="hide filtered-content" id="example1">hi</div>
<div class="hide filtered-content" id="example2">hi-2</div>


const filter = function () {
        var $current = $('ul.list-filter li');

        $current.on('click', function() {
            var $dataType = $(this).attr('data-target'),
                $dataContent = $('.filtered-content[id]');

            $('ul.list-filter li').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
            if ($dataContent === $dataType) {
                $dataContent.removeClass('hide');
            } else {
                $dataContent.addClass('hide');
            }
        });
    };
```

Comment: Your question has an html syntax error around the unclosed ids on the `li` elements.  Edit: and the parent ul class.

Comment: `$dataContent = $('.filtered-content[id]');`  I don't see the `filtered-content` class any where.

Comment: `$dataContent` will be a jQuery object.  It will never equal a string value.

Comment: `$('.filtered-content[id]');` is `id` meant to be the id of the item?  it's currently a string literal (but `var id` isn't defined anyway)

Comment: @Taplar thanks for that, I forgot the closing " when I adding in the dummy classes and updated the classes.

Comment: @freedomn-m yes it was meant to be the id of the item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you need.

```js
$(function(){
  var filteredContent = $('.filtered-content div');
  $('ul.list-filter li').on('click', function(){
    $('ul.list-filter li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    var $dataType = $(this).attr('data-target');
    filteredContent.hide();
    $($dataType).show();
  });
});
```

```css
.hide{ display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="list-filter">
  <li data-target="#example1">Example 1</li>
  <li data-target="#example2">Example 2</li>
</ul>

<div class="filtered-content">
  <div class="hide" id="example1">hi</div>
  <div class="hide" id="example2">hi-2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly,** You are missing `""` close tag at `class="list-filter`, `data-target="#example1`  and `data-target="#example2`

**Secondly,** You have not called `filter` function. It should look like this

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    filter();
});
```

**Thirdly,** `$dataContent = $('.filtered-content[id]');` is incorrect. It might fix like this `$dataContent = $(dataType);`

**Finally,** You should add `data-content` class, then handle jQuery like `$(".data-content").addClass('hide');` instead.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    filter();
});


const filter = function () {
        var $current = $('ul.list-filter li');

        $current.on('click', function() {
            var dataType = $(this).attr('data-target'),
                $dataContent = $(dataType);
            
            $('ul.list-filter li').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
            
            $(".data-content").addClass('hide');
            $dataContent.removeClass('hide');
        });
    };
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}

.active{
   color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="list-filter">
  <li data-target="#example1">Example 1</li>
  <li data-target="#example2">Example 2</li>
</ul>

<div class="hide data-content" id="example1">hi</div>
<div class="hide data-content" id="example2">hi-2</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help @Jasmine Ibikunle

Answer (score -1):

I think what you meant to do was to get the `data-target` from the clicked element and show the div whose id matches that `data-target` while hiding the rest of the elements

So this is probably what you need

```
.hide {
  display: none;
}

<ul class="list-filter>
  <li data-target="#example1>Example 1</li>
  <li data-target="#example2>Example 2</li>
</ul>

<div class="filtered-content hide" id="example1">hi</div>
<div class="filtered-content hide" id="example2">hi-2</div>


const filter = function () {
        var $current = $('ul.list-filter li');

        $current.on('click', function() {
            var targetId = $(this).attr('data-target'),
                $allContent = $(`div.filtered-content`);
                $dataContent = $(targetId);

            $('ul.list-filter li').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
            $allContent.addClass('hide');
            $dataContent.removeClass('hide');
        });
    };
```